# Javascript nested array on developer tools prints different when object vs. printed with toString()

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

I'm getting an odd issue with a nested array I have in a program I'm working on.

When I print out the nested array in console.log as a set of values it prints out correctly.

Ex.

```
console.log("Array: " + arr) //Array: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1
```

However when I print them out as the object I'm getting entirely different values right after it. After expanding it out on chrome's developer tools I get.

```
console.log(arr)//(2)[Array(2), Array(2)]
0: [2][1,4]
1: [2][0,1]
```

Sometimes javascript/developer tools are weird and so I'm consulting SO.

I don't believe I have pointer issues where between the two print statements something is accessing a value in the `arr`. They happen right after eachother and the basic pseudocode on the main nested array manipulation is a simple increment of +1.

I couldn't find anything online, but wanted to confirm there are no odd issues with chrome developer tools or javascript when printing objects vs. values. Unfortunately, I believe this is as concise an example I can make and don't know what example code would be otherwise helpful in this case.

One other odd issue I'm seeing on the same matrix object that when I try to access an element `i.e arr[0][0][0]` I'm getting an entirely different value than I would have expected.

Thanks in advance and if there turns out to be no known issues/considerations with either the developer tools or javascript then I will close this post.

**Update:**
In the developer tools this line when expanded:

[image: Array element from console.log]

Returns an entirely new set of values. As you can see, the 14 became 67 when expanded out. 
[image]

Comment: How did you create the array? Consoles are not standardised, they try to be helpful.

Comment: Basic array creation was:  //create three arrays {array1 = new Array(size)} then place array 3 into each element of array 2 and array 2 into each element array 1. I did a deep clone of each slice of the array when I generated the nested matrix to ensure that memory allocation was unique per element.  I would have put more details on it, but the array seems to resolve correctly on the first print statement and is what I would expect. The second print statement right after the first one doesn't line up with expectations, although it is the same object printed directly after eachother.

Comment: You need to show more of the code that you are using.

Comment: "*I don't believe I have pointer issues where between the two print statements something is accessing a value in the arr.*" - the issue with the references is when you modify the logged objects *after* they were logged (and before you look at them in the console).

Comment: The Is `console.log() async or sync?` in particular is helpful. Thank you. I'm guessing it has something to do with the lazy evaluation however I don't think I ever increment up to the values I'm seeing. For example, the 67 value seems hard to believe an issue with synchronization. I will look into my code to review.  I will not close this thread yet until I have had the chance to confirm duplication.

Comment: I played around with `firefox's` developer tools and the issue no longer seems to be present. blurg. Thanks for the help everyone. Wish I had considered it an browser issue sooner. Guess it's time to welcome firefox ....

Answer (score 0):

```
"Array: " + arr
```

This creates a string, by calling `arr.toString()` (that's how `+` works).  Array's `toString()` joins the `toString()`s of all of the elements by commas.  Therefore, if your array is nested, it will recursively flatten it.

```
console.log(arr)
```

This passes the array itself to `console.log()`, which has special handling to display objects.

Comment: That doesn't explain why new values are generated that aren't there when printing it out by string. i.e as an example [0,0,1] turns to [4,0,3] directly after eachother.

Comment: I've added an update to the thread with an example of generated numbers that don't align between the initial array and the expanded array.